# "Cannot resolve type "my_type"". Data type error. C# MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have TeamsPage xaml page and its viewmodel TeamsPageViewmodel. This Viewmodel has observable collection Players. And I want to show it on my page with collection view, but I have an error when i want to display name in cell in CollectionView with datatemplate.

TeamsPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="_153502_Tolstoi.UI.Pages.TeamsPage"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewModels="using:_153502_Tolstoi.UI.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="using:_153502_Tolstoi.Domain.Entities"
             x:DataType="viewModels:TeamsPageViewModel"
             x:Name="Page"
             Title="TeamsPage">

    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="Loaded"
            Command="{Binding UpdateGroupListCommand }"/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>

    <Grid
        Margin="20"
        RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto"
        ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto"
        ColumnSpacing="20"
        RowSpacing="20">

        <Picker
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            TextColor="Black"
            Title="Pick a team"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeam}"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}">

            <Picker.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
                    Command="{Binding UpdateMembersListCommand}">
                </toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>
            </Picker.Behaviors>

        </Picker>

        <CollectionView 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="CollectionView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
            SelectionMode="None">

            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <Label
                    Text="No tours found!"
                    TextColor="LightGray"
                    FontSize="28"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Player">
                    <Border 
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                        Margin="10,10,10,10"
                        HeightRequest="120"
                        Padding="20">
                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10" ></RoundRectangle>
                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   FontSize="18" 
                                   MaximumWidthRequest="120"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start"
                                   MaxLines="3"  
                                   Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <ActivityIndicator
            IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
            IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Color="{StaticResource Primary}"
            HeightRequest="100"
            WidthRequest="100"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

TeamsPage.xaml.cs

```
using _153502_Tolstoi.UI.ViewModels;

namespace _153502_Tolstoi.UI.Pages;

public partial class TeamsPage : ContentPage
{
    private TeamsPageViewModel _teamsPageViewModel;
    public TeamsPage(TeamsPageViewModel teamsPageViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _teamsPageViewModel = teamsPageViewModel;
    }
}
```

TeamsPageViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using _153502_Tolstoi.Application.Abstractions;
using _153502_Tolstoi.Domain.Entities;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace _153502_Tolstoi.UI.ViewModels
{
    public partial class TeamsPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly ITeamService _teamService;
        private readonly IPlayerService _playerService;
        public TeamsPageViewModel(ITeamService teamService, IPlayerService
            playerService)
        {
            _teamService = teamService;
            _playerService = playerService;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } = new();
        public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; } = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        Team selectedTeam;

        [RelayCommand]
        async void UpdateGroupList() => await GetTeams();

        [RelayCommand]
        async void UpdateMembersList() => await GetPlayers();

        public async Task GetTeams()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var cources = await _teamService.GetAllAsync();
            await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
            {
                Teams.Clear();
                foreach (var cource in cources)
                    Teams.Add(cource);
            });
            SelectedTeam = Teams.FirstOrDefault();
            IsBusy = false;
        }

        public async Task GetPlayers()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var players = (await _teamService.GetByIdAsync(SelectedTeam.Id)).Players;
            await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
            {
                Players.Clear();
                foreach (var player in players)
                    Players.Add(player);
            });
            IsBusy = false;
        }
        
    }
}
```

error:
`error XFC0000  Cannot resolve type "using:_153502_Tolstoi.Domain.Entities:models:Player".  71`

I have same code on my other project and it works normal, but models in this project were not in library. Maybe it is a reason of error, but how to solve it

Edited: i solved it by removing x:DataType=(My viewmodel) and x:DataType=(Player). But cant be some more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the type is defined in a different assembly, you have to [specify the assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces#declaring-namespaces-for-types)

```
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Behaviors;assembly=BehaviorsLibrary"
```

Comment: I tried it and it works too!